# Make price attribute read-only

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, event-observer

We have make custom module as of this explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384120/magento-read-only-and-hidden-product-attributes

We missing something, because it is not working, we have done this:

Create new module in app/code/community/Wescon/Hidden/

etc/config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

  <config>
<modules>
    <Wescon_Hidden>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Wescon_Hidden>
</modules>
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_edit_action>
            <observers>
                <Wescon_Hidden>
                    <class>hidden/observer</class>
                    <method>wescon_hidden</method>
                </Wescon_Hidden>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_edit_action>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

class Wescon_Hidden_Model_Observer
{

public function wescon_hidden($observer) {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $product = $event->getProduct();
    $product->lockAttribute('price');
}

}
```

app/etc/modules/Wescon_Hidden.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<config>
<modules>
    <Wescon_Hidden>
        <active>true</active>
        <codepool>community</codepool>
    </Wescon_Hidden>
</modules>
</config>
```

We have try with **catalog_product_load_after** but nothing work.

Does somebody have the solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `config` nodes are not closed in xml files, and you have same function twice in your observer. Your module might not even be readable by Magento.

Comment: We have try with /config and erase the second observer, not working. Thanks Prateek for help

Comment: "p" will be in caps in "codePool" in your 'Wescon_Hidden.xml' file. Then check if module is active in admin.

Comment: Have change the P from codePool but no change. I see my module in system/advance and is active, but it do nothing.

Comment: Try adding some logging in observer and see if it is getting called at all.

Comment: Do you have any example? Sorry it is my first module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of hours lost with this module, we have trash it and just go inside the database and frontend_input: price to label, because we already use a auto sku generator and it work with sku and now with price and special price.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and got it to working with one minor modification in config.xml file. Below is the updated code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Wescon_Hidden>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Wescon_Hidden>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <hidden>
                <class>Wescon_Hidden_Model</class>
            </hidden>
        </models>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_edit_action>
                <observers>
                    <Wescon_Hidden>
                        <class>hidden/observer</class>
                        <method>wescon_hidden</method>
                    </Wescon_Hidden>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_edit_action>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Models node was not defined and so, Magento was not able to load your observer. If you were working in developer mode, you might've figured that out.
All other parts of code are fine, just remember to have appropriate closing tags as well in all the xml files. For reference, below are other files :

app/etc/modules/Wescon_Hidden.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Wescon_Hidden>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Wescon_Hidden>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/community/Wescon/Hidden/Model/Observer.php file :

```
<?php
    class Wescon_Hidden_Model_Observer {

        public function wescon_hidden($observer) {
            $event = $observer->getEvent();
            $product = $event->getProduct();
            $product->lockAttribute('price');
        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't know why, but after change, not working, I don't know if the version can have effect? I use 1.9.2.4 :( Thanks Prateek

Comment: Version should not have any effect on that. Make sure all files are at correct places, clear your cache too. Check the compilation status. And also check if you have any other observer defined with the key `Wescon_Hidden` in your installtion. It should be inside config.xml files of your modules.